# Should I find a way to programmatically insert an ID into html

Tags: javascript, dom

I came across an issue recently where I wanted to manipulate the text of a span tag. I do not know much about dom, but since the element wanted to manipulate it didn't have an ID, and only was a span tag, I decided to inspect element the webpage, and add in and id.

for example

```
<span>some random text</span>

<span id="newID">some random text with an id</span>
```

Now, i can use dom to manipulate it

```
document.getElementById("newID").textContent="newtext";
```

Is there a way to give an element an ID without inspecting element, or is there a better way to do it, such as getting the element by tagname and figuring out which number in the array it is somehow.

Another question I have is if anyone has a webscraping tool used for finding element names, id's, values, etc. This is an example of one, but is only supported in internet explore, which doesnt support many websites. [iwb2learnertool](http://the-automator.com/download/iWB2_Learner.exe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some examples that how you can find a specific element, hope this can help

```js
// If the content is certain
// Find the span that the content is "Test 1"
[...document.querySelectorAll('span')].find(e => e.innerText === 'Test 1').innerText = 'Changed 1';

// If the order is certain
// Find the second span in element with class "container"
document.querySelector('.container span:nth-of-type(2)').innerText = 'Changed 2';

// If the previous element is certain
// Find the span next to an element with an id "some-id"
document.querySelector('#some-id + span').innerText = 'Changed 3';
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Test 1</span>
  <br>
  <span>Test 2</span>
  <br id="some-id" >
  <span>Test 3</span>
</div>
```